# Oracle developer tools for visual studio 2015,dot.net framework 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g

I want to connect to remote **oracle database** through **visual studio 2015** using server explorer.

My project's has framework version 4.So can you tell me which version to install?

I am using oracle database client 11g and my machine is 32 bit.

Please help me, I am fresher in `asp.net`.

Comment: ODT.NET managed and unmanaged driver